# ERRO 1442 MYSQL, como resolver?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Após inserir em "banco1.clientes" eu quero inserir o mesmo conteudo em "banco2.Clientes", mas o erro aparece.

Vi que o MySql nao permite duas operações na mesma tabela, porém são bancos diferentes.

Essa trigger estava funcionando a um tempo atrás, mas agora retorna esse codigo, o que posso ter feito de errado?

Codigo:

```
INSERT INTO banco1.Clientes VALUES (42,'mariana', '1998-05-08', '48381856' '4539-6', 'ananana', 'oqe?', '162', 'sasnaush', 'qsjqijqiwj',
                                    'SP', '13720000');

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insereBanco1 AFTER INSERT
ON banco1.Clientes FOR EACH ROW
    /* insercao */
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO banco2.Clientes (id, nome, dat_nascimento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cep)
            SELECT id, nome, dat_nascimento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cep FROM banco1.Clientes WHERE
            id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM banco2.Clientes);
        END;

$$
```

ERRO:

```
15:27:13    INSERT INTO banco1.Clientes VALUES (42,'mariana', '1998-05-08', '48381856' '4539-6', 'ananana', 'oqe?', '162', 'sasnaush', 'qsjqijqiwj',          'SP', '13720000') Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'clientes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.  0.000 sec
```

Comment: Informe a descrição do erro.

Comment: pronto! Inseri o erro

Comment: Você está fazendo um `SELECT` na linha sendo que ainda não finalizou a operação de atualização. Para obter os valores dessa linha use as palavras chave [`OLD` e `NEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta Augusto! Vou estudar a questão de old e new, pois ainda nao aprendi.